# Blender Python path directory for file output node

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, compositing-nodes, path

i'm trying to make a little script to change all file outputs node in my compositing scene, relatively to my file output render directory.

For example, if i render something in 
/Render/Combined/Combined_####
i want the file outputs nodes to create some folders in 
/Render/

So far, i've got this :

```
import bpy

import os

 # Get absolute path:
filepath = bpy.context.scene.render.filepath
absolutepath = bpy.path.abspath(filepath)

 # set the path for all file output nodes:
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    for node in scene.node_tree.nodes:
        if node.type == 'OUTPUT_FILE':
            node.base_path = absolutepath
```

And it works, but i can't find a way to get to the "superior" directory...
Is someone out here have some answers ? thank you very much !

Comment: What do you mean by "superior" directory?

Comment: I mean the parent directory, if my render output ils /render/combined my parent directory is /render

Comment: So, using your example, you want to get the parent directory of absolutepath?

Comment: yep exactly ! (sorry if i'm not clear, not really good in english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `../..` at the end of your `absolutepath`, like this

```
node.base_path = absolutepath+'../..'
```

or if you insist on getting the actual path cleanly, you can use the python `os` module to split the path into parts and then join them again except the last two

```
import bpy
import os

 # Get absolute path:
filepath = bpy.context.scene.render.filepath
absolutepath = bpy.path.abspath(filepath)

path = os.path.normpath(absolutepath)
parts = path.split(os.sep)

absolutepath = os.sep.join(parts[:-2])

# set the path for all file output nodes:
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    for node in scene.node_tree.nodes:
        if node.type == 'OUTPUT_FILE':
            node.base_path = absolutepath
```

If you want this to work even if your original path has a filename in the end, add

```
absolutepath, file = os.path.split(absolutepath)
```

before `path = os.path.normpath(absolutepath)`

Comment: this one is perfect too ! and the [:-2] give me control on the number of directory to "climb up" really good to know ! thanks for the quick answer ! i have one more question, i tried to use that and replace the last line by           node.base_path = absolutepath + "\new directory"           to create a new directory, but it doesn't work, do you have an idea ?

Comment: I don't know if blender auto-creates directories. Use `os.mkdir` to create it first

Comment: i found a way (i think it's not the good one, but it works); when i create the name i add   `"\_"` followed by the right name, but i had to keep the underscore, i don't know why but doesn't work without... Example : `node.base_path = absolutepath + "\_" + "name of the new directory"`

Comment: That's weird... In my case it does not need the underscore, and when I put it there, I can see it in the created directory (mkdir not needed btw)

Comment: perhaps it's about being on windows ? anyway it allows the file output to be quickly recognizable so not a real problem ! thank you for your quick answers !

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(*your_path*)
```

Comment: Might be useful for new Python coders to see the code in context with a bit of an explanation.